# Bluetooth Adapter Invisible

Tags: bluetooth

I recently uninstalled my atheros bluetooth suite and reinstalled it again. But this time the bluetooth driver is not listed in the Device Manager.

I refreshed it and it is still invisible.

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 as a second os and bluetooth works fine in it. How can I make windows to detect this adapter?
I have windows 7 and Atheros AR5BBUI2 adapter.

Comment: Did you reinstall both the bluetooth driver and the bluetooth stack?

Comment: which version of Windows & bluetooth adapter do you have?

Comment: I reinstalled both the stack and driver but they are of no use.